# ASP .Net Core Http [GET] for collection of nested objects

Tags: asp.net-core, http-get

I want to use a collection of nested objects in a query string 
like

```
public class Range 
{
  public decimal From {get;set},
  public decimal To {get;set}
} 

public class SearchParams 
{
  public IEnumerable<Range> Sizes {get;set;}
}
```

I know that better to use POST for this but I can't change an existing contract
because of backward compatibility

So the question - Is there any option to pass it in a query string? or pass it as a string and to parse it in server

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you action method receives a `SearchParams` as parameter , which is named as `para` .

```
public IActionResult Index(SearchParams para)
{
    return new JsonResult(para);
}
```

you can send the `GET` request as below :

```
GET https://localhost:44386/?para.sizes[0].from=1.1&para.sizes[0].To=1.2&para.sizes[1].from=2.1&para.sizes[1].To=2.2& HTTP/1.1
```

Query String :

```
para.sizes[0].from=1.1&para.sizes[0].To=1.2&para.sizes[1].from=2.1&para.sizes[1].To=2.2
```

and the response will be :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpccmVwb3J0XDIwMThcMTBcMTFcU08uR2V0Q29sbGVjdGlvblxBcHA=?=

{
  "sizes": [{
    "from": 1.1,
    "to": 1.2
  }, {
    "from": 2.1,
    "to": 2.2
  }]
}
```

Comment: @user681055: In case it's not obvious from the monstrosity that is that query string, you should avoid sending complex request data via GET. Do a POST instead.