# Binding a collection of a complex type with other properties from a query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core v2.1, I have a controller inheriting from `Controller` that  contains an action with a parameter decorated with `FromQuery` based on the following model:

```
public class PagingControl<T>
{
    public ColumnSort[] ColumnSorts { get; set; }

    public T ColumnFilters { get; set; }

    public int Page { get; set; }

    public int PerPage { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnSort
{
    public string Field { get; set; }

    public SortType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum SortType
{
    Asc = 0,
    Desc
}
```

The generic parameter represents a flat poco with nullable properties that provide well defined columns and values to filter with. The `PagingControl<T>` model describes all parameters required to implement paging with the action.

The `ColumnSorts` property is a collection as multiple successive column sorting is possible.

I have read [Array or List in query string does not get parsed](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7712) however if I understand this, I cannot have a single model that accepts all query parameters.

In order to successfully implement the full functionality of paging, all parameters are required. This worked fine when `ColumnSorts` was not a collection, consistent with single column sorting.

Does anyone know of a workaround with a query string for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you described above has already been fixed. In addition, even if it's is not fixed, you could walk around it by `[FromQuery(Name="xxx")]`. See [dougbu's walkaround](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7712#issuecomment-397003420).

It seems that you're using the `[ApiController]`, I test it with `2.1.302` and `2.1.402`, it works flawlessly.

Let's say you want to query against `MyColoumnFilter`, which will be used as your `T ColumnFilters` in the `PagingControl<T>` class :

```
public class MyColumnFilter
{
    public string FieldA { get; set; }
    public string FieldB { get; set; }
}
```

and your action method on server side is :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]PagingControl<MyColumnFilter> pc)
    { 
        return new JsonResult(pc);
    } 

    // ...
}
```

If you send a request as below :

```
GET https://localhost:5001/api/my?page=1&perPage=10&columnFilters.fieldA=1&columnFilters.fieldB=2&columnSorts[0].Field=cs1&columnSorts[0].Type=Asc&columnSorts[1].Field=cs2&columnSorts[1].Type=Desc HTTP/1.1
```

it will work as expected :

[image]

The querystring can be divided into 4 parts:

1. page : an `int` of 1
2. perPage : an `int` of 10
3. columnFilters : `columnFilters.fieldA=1&columnFilters.fieldB=2`
4. columnSorts[] : since the `ColumnSorts` is an array, we should construct the parameter like **`columnSorts[0].Field=xx&columnSorts[0].Type=Asc&columnSorts[1].Field=...`**

As a side note, it will make the querystring rather complicated if you use the `GET` http method. See [Chris Pratt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52757072/10091607) under my another answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73080835/16821115 can you suggest something for my query ?