# Unable to map FromQuery to complex object in .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

In short my problem statement is that im unable to perform mapping from FromQuery to my complex object which is as follows.

```
/// <summary>
/// QueryModel class models sorting, batching
/// requirements for set of records.
/// </summary>
public class QueryModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// SortBy list provides provision to hold all the properties
    /// that will act as basis for sorting the records.
    /// e.g. Resource, Diagram No, Days Run, Dates.
    /// </summary>
    public List<SortBy> SortBy { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ordinal indicates the position of record in the batch.
    /// </summary>
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates total of records that can be transmitted.
    /// </summary>
    public int BatchSize { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This class act as driver model for sort
/// using it's members as its basis.
/// </summary>
public class SortBy
{
    private string _columnHeaderName;
    private SortOrder _sortOrder;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates the column header name incoming from UI.
    /// </summary>
    public string ColumnNameAndSortOder
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}, {1}", _columnHeaderName, _sortOrder);
        }
        set
        {
            string[] temp = value.Split(',');
            _columnHeaderName = temp[0].Trim();
            _sortOrder = (SortOrder)Enum.Parse(typeof(SortOrder), temp[1].Trim());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The enumeration required for ordering the records.
    /// </summary>
    internal enum SortOrder
    {
        None,
        Asc,
        Desc,
    }
}
```

Here's my controller action with the complex object.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<MapHeader>>> GetMaps([FromQuery, BindRequired] string geoCode,
                                                                         [FromQuery, BindRequired] string geoId,
                                                                         [FromQuery, BindRequired] QueryModel queryModelParams)
```

I get values for ordinal and batchsize properties properly but mapping for property SortBy has list count = 0 during GET Call.

Unable to figure where it is going wrong.

Any help or pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `queryModelParams.SortBy[0].ColumnNameAndSortOder=aa,1` to solve this issue. Like below:

```
https://localhost:44355/api/Test/GetMaps?geoCode=1&geoId=1&queryModelParams.SortBy[0].ColumnNameAndSortOder=aa,1&queryModelParams.SortBy[1].ColumnNameAndSortOder=aa,0
```

**Test Result**

[image]

[image]